# Add character to date format using regex

Tags: notepad++

How do I add e.g. `-` or `.` to the date format `2006 05 12` using `regex` in Notepad++

Comment: I am a newbie so I'm not familiar with regex at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NotePad++ press `Ctrl+H`

Find What: `(\d{4})\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2})`

Replace with: `\1-\2-\3`.

`(\d{4})`

- `\d` means digit
- `{4}` four times
- () to be able to refer to this group in brackets by number - `\1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture first the "date" and then replace it with the new one modified.

search for `(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (\d{2})` 
replace with `$1/$2/$3`

$1, $2, $3 means 1st, 2nd and 3rd capute.
You can do also smth like `$3.$2.$1` if you need `2006 05 12` => `12.05.2006`